# Mongoose save model with object field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to save a mongoose model that has a schema with an object field.  When I try to save I get the error below.  What am I missing?

I suspect this might have something to do with how mongoose objects are not quite like standard javascript objects since they are altered.  However, what confounds me is that I'm doing exactly the same thing in another section of my code with a schema that has a nested object field and that works.

What I've tried:

- To test, I changed my schema to list resulttype and resultround as individual fields without nesting and when I did that it worked.
- I also tried creating an object with key value pairs outside of my model and then pass that object to my model.  That did not work either.

Schema

```
 var ResultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    event_id : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    event_name: String,
    event_type: String,
    resultdate : String,
    resulttype: {
        type: String, 
        round: Number
    },
    // resulttype: String,
    // resultround: Number,
 });
```

Model save:

```
var newResult = new ResultModel({
    // objNewResult
    event_id: req.body.eventid,//hidden field
    event_name: req.body.eventname, //hidden field
    resultdate: req.body.resultdate,
    // resulttype: resulttypelist,
    // resultround: resultroundlist,
    resulttype: {
        type: req.body.resulttypelist, 
        round: req.body.resultroundlist
    }
});

newResult.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("SUCCESSFUL RESULT ADDITION");
        }
    });
```

Error:

```
ValidationError: results validation failed: resulttype: Cast to String failed for value "{ type: 'standard', round: '1' }" at path "resulttype"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`type`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) is a reserved keyword in Mongoose schemas. It's used to specify the type of the field. When you specify this:

```
resulttype: {
    type: String, 
    round: String
},
```

Mongoose will consider the field `resulttype` to be a String. So you have to use another name than type.

Answer (score 1):

`type` is a reserved key:

> By default, if you have an object with key 'type' in your schema, mongoose will interpret it as a type declaration. [Source](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey).

So right now, `resulttype` is expected to be of type `String`. You can use a different key instead:

*Schema*:

```
resulttype: {
  resultType: String, 
  round: String
},
```

*Model Save:*

```
var newResult = new ResultModel({
  // ...

  resulttype: {
    resultType: req.body.resulttypelist, 
    round: parseFloat(req.body.resultroundlist),
  }
});
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but that was a typo on my part.  I've edited the schema to show String for `round`.  I still get the same error.

Comment: To test, I left my schema as number but I still get the same error when I cast user parseInt or parseFloat. `message: 'Cast to String failed for value "{ type: \'standard\', round: 1 }" at path "resulttype"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"{ type: \'standard\', round: 1 }"',`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That was the issue.  I marked the answer provided by MikaS just because they gave the correct answer first based on the timestamps I see.